# naming convention in rails. why isn't my services file being found in the app folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a services file called TitleParser in app/services... a custom made folder. The file is called titleparser.rb

```
class TitleParser
  attr_reader :connection

  def initialize(orig_url)
    @connection = Faraday.new(orig_url)
  end

  def obtain_title
    response = parse(connection.get)
    require 'pry' ; binding.pry
  end

  private

  def parse(response)
    JSON.parse(response.body)
  end
end
```

In my model, I in app/models I have a model called Link that calls it.

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :shorten_url
  before_create :set_defaults

  def shorten_url
    self.short_url = "bit.ly-remix/" + SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(6)
  end

  def set_defaults
    self.clicks = 0 if clicks.blank?
    self.title = TitleParser.new(orig_url).obtain_title
  end
end
```

I was getting a undefined Link::TitleParser for hours until I renamed the file in services to title_parser.rb. What is going on here? What conventional rule is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a standard Rails naming convention issue that you've run into.  Note how you've named the class:

```
class TitleParser
```

With that name, Rails will want a file named `title_parser.rb`

Comment: This would be a good reference although does not explicitly describe `app/services` directory: [Ruby and Rails Naming Conventions](http://itsignals.cascadia.com.au/?p=7)